RsBuild react project got can not find module error for png image file
I am now setting up my RactJS project build with RsBuild,
in my main.css file, I have this
 background-image: url(/background.png)

but when I run rsbuild dev command, I got this error:
Error: HookWebpackError: Cannot find module '/background.png'

I checked RsBuild doc, can not find out how to resolve this error, can anyone help me with this?

Ran into this issue and turns out it was just a path resolution problem. Any additional details on where the png file is stored relative to your entry file?
